ROS2 Docker node to Host node - why it works?
I finally made the communication between Dockerized node and node on Host machine. Also another computer on the same subnet can listen to the Dockerized node.
But why does it work? How is network resolved between Docker container and host machine in ros environment? Why i dont need any port setup? How does the node discovery work?
Using Ubuntu 22.04 on RPi 4.
Using Docker Engine.
FROM arm64v8/ros:humble-ros-core-jammy

# install ros package
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-demo-nodes-cpp \
  ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-demo-nodes-py && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# launch ros package
CMD ["ros2", "run", "demo_nodes_cpp", "talker"]

docker build -t demo_talker .
docker run -it demo_talker

ros2 run demo_nodes_cpp listener

Could the same be setup for the use of Docker Desktop on Mac/Windows? I would just want not to use the --net host (network_mode: host) setting on docker. Use case would be to have node in docker and another on remote linux machine. Anyone did this successfully?
note: I am signed as root on the Host machine to listen properly:
https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/1318
